# Use random values from JSON without repeating them?

Tags: ruby, regex, json

I'm writing a little Ruby Sinatra app that replaces string fragments with a regex in a Mad Libs type of way. I'm loading in a JSON object to get the strings, and I'm getting random values using the "sample" method. This doesn't solve the problem of only using values one time. Can anyone help?

Source:

```
get '/' do

  paragraph = ""

  vocab = JSON.parse(File.read('music-journalism-vocabulary.json'))

  artist_types = ["male","female","plural"]

  artist = ""
  artist_type = artist_types.delete artist_types.sample
  artist = vocab["artist-#{artist_type}"].sample
  case artist_type
  when "male"
    artist_posessive_pronoun = "his"
  when "female"
    artist_posessive_pronoun = "her"
  when "plural"
    artist_posessive_pronoun = "their"
  else
  end

  sentences = []
  sentences << vocab["sentence-intro"].sample
  sentences << vocab["sentence-middle"].sample
  sentences << vocab["sentence-conclusion"].sample

  sentences.each_with_index do |iter, i|
    sentence = iter.dup
    sentence_with_replacement = sentence.dup

    # Handle plural agreement
    if (artist_type == "plural")
      sentence_with_replacement.gsub!(/\*artist-subject\*/, "*artist-subject*s")
    end

    word_types = vocab.keys
    word_types.each_with_index do |word_type, j|

      sentence = ''
      while sentence != sentence_with_replacement do
        sentence = sentence_with_replacement.dup
        sentence_with_replacement = sentence.sub(/\*#{word_type}\*/, vocab[word_type].sample)
      end
    end

    sentence_with_replacement.gsub!(/\*artist\*/, artist)
    # Subject-pronoun agreement
    sentence_with_replacement.gsub!(/\*posessive-pronoun\*/, artist_posessive_pronoun)

    sentence_with_replacement[0] = sentence_with_replacement.capitalize[0]
    paragraph << "#{sentence_with_replacement} "
  end

  paragraph

end
```

JSON file:

```
{
    "artist-male": ["Skrillex",
                "Bon Iver",
                "A$AP Rocky",
                "Earl Sweatshirt",
                "Frank Ocean"
              ],
    "artist-female": ["Grimes"
              ],
    "artist-plural": ["Death Grips",
                    "Best Coast",
                    "Toro Y Moi",
                    "Odd Future",
                    "Gold Panda",
                    "Icona Pop",
                    "Foxygen",
                    "Four Tet"
              ],

    "adverb": [
        "inarguably",
        "inevitably",
        "reliably",
        "positively",
        "truly",
        "genuinely",
        "sharply",
        "intricately",
        "hopelessly"
    ],
    "adjective": [
        "chrome-plated",
        "lonely",
        "mossy",
        "poised",
        "lysergic",
        "solid-state",
        "lyrical",
        "id-driven",
        "rubbery",
        "hard",
        "striated",
        "electroacoustic",
        "tarnished",
        "radiophonic",
        "wispy",
        "soul-deep",
        "minimal",
        "lulling",
        "insular",
        "nostalgic",
        "vacant",
        "feminine",
        "sensual",
        "meditative",
        "somnambulant",
        "velvet-gloved",
        "melodic",
        "confessional",
        "rollercoaster",
        "thrilling",
        "crunchy",
        "lush",
        "deranged",
        "shambolic",
        "stalwart",
        "ephemeral",
        "gentle",
        "angular",
        "sanctified",
        "austere",
        "cinematic",
        "focused",
        "sheer",
        "purring",
        "rangy",
        "jittery",
        "world-weary",
        "slippery",
        "colorful",
        "multi-layered",
        "complex",
        "tentative",
        "apocalyptic",
        "eerie",
        "withering",
        "clattering",
        "20th-century",
        "impressionist",
        "Glass-ian",
        "distorted",
        "raw",
        "wild",
        "gleaming",
        "evocative",
        "otherworldly",
        "melancholic",
        "lugubrious",
        "phlegmatic",
        "sanguine",
        "analog",
        "delirious",
        "Aristotelian",
        "slick",
        "rudderless",
        "radio-ready",
        "knotty",
        "demonstrative",
        "thousand-watt"
    ],
    "adjective-prefix": [
        "quasi-",
        "aggro-",
        "hobo-",
        "über-"
    ],
    "comparative": [
        "darker",
        "lonelier",
        "sharper",
        "subtler"
    ],
    "artist-subject": [
        "mannerist",
        "architect",
        "enfant terrible",
        "spectre",
        "vaudevillian",
        "sine qua non"
    ],
    "album-subject": [
        "endeavor",
        "release",
        "amalgamation",
        "offering",
        "approach",
        "diversion",
        "reimagining",
        "capital-A album"
    ],
    "style-noun": [
        "skronk",
        "techno-future",
        "jangle-funk",
        "jungle-metal",
        "Philly-soul",
        "skate-punk",
        "synth-schlock",
        "high-goth",
        "alt-country",
        "Afrobeat",
        "French chanson",
        "pop balladry"
    ],
    "meaning-noun": [
        "legacy",
        "monumentality",
        "séance",
        "splendor",
        "drama",
        "grit",
        "sexiness",
        "mutability",
        "tragedy",
        "grief",
        "ardor",
        "celebration",
        "ennui",
        "euphoria",
        "beauty",
        "majesty",
        "nimbleness",
        "humility",
        "aggression"
    ],
    "meaning-verb": [
        "flaunt",
        "sweep",
        "woo",
        "conjure"
    ],
    "judgement-noun": [
        "confidence",
        "boldness",
        "swagger",
        "vigor",
        "prowess",
        "mastery"
    ],
    "judgement-adjective": [
        "unsurpassed",
        "entrancing",
        "enlightenment-inducing",
        "universal",
        "well-rehearsed",
        "impeccable",
        "revelatory",
        "transcendent",
        "stunning"
    ],
    "judgement-verb": [
        "triumph",
        "succeed",
        "soar",
        "captivate",
        "shimmer"
    ],
    "technique-noun": [
        "white noise",
        "baritone",
        "rhythm guitar",
        "soliloquy",
        "beatbox",
        "crescendo",
        "production",
        "drones",
        "whiplash",
        "showboating",
        "schtick"
    ],
    "technique-noun-plural": [
        "hard angles",
        "pulsations",
        "bons mots",
        "verbal gymnastics",
        "grooves",
        "strings",
        "drones",
        "acerbics",
        "harmonies",
        "sonorities",
        "cadences",
        "mantras",
        "vocoders",
        "squelches"
    ],
    "technique-verb": [
        "sway",
        "swagger",
        "assemble",
        "croon",
        "protest",
        "transform",
        "dissolve"
    ],
    "character-phrase": [
      "with money to burn",
      "against all odds",
      "par excellence",
      "for the *non-music-reference* generation",
      "with a yen for *drug*",
      "ready to cash in"
    ],
    "drug": [
      "barbituates",
      "opiates",
      "box wine",
      "laudanum",
      "mescaline",
      "dead-stock quaaludes"
    ],
    "non-music-reference": [
      "Buzzfeed",
      "Twitter",
      "Honey Boo Boo",
      "Hulu",
      "MySpace"
    ],
    "sentence-intro": ["Amid the growing fashionability of *adjective* *technique-noun* and *adjective* *technique-noun*, *artist*'s new *album-subject* distinguishes itself with *meaning-noun* and *judgement-noun*.",
                      "*artist* reappeared with *posessive-pronoun* latest *album-subject* as *adjective* *artist-subject* *character-phrase*."
                      ],
    "sentence-middle": [
        "*posessive-pronoun* latest *album-subject* is discernably *posessive-pronoun* attempt to *technique-verb* the *adjective* *technique-noun-plural* that a more typically *style-noun* *album-subject* would employ, with particular attention paid to the *adjective* delivery of *adjective-prefix**adjective* *meaning-noun*.",
        "*posessive-pronoun* latest *album-subject* is *comparative*, *judgement-adjective*; *adverb* *adjective* and *adjective*, full of *technique-noun* and *adjective* *technique-noun*.",
        "The *adjective* *judgement-noun* of *posessive-pronoun* *adjective* *meaning-noun* *judgement-verb*s, and *posessive-pronoun* *style-noun* *judgement-noun* is *adverb* *judgement-adjective*.",
        "To say *posessive-pronoun* *album-subject* is \"*adjective*\" is a gross understatement—in the hands of *artist*, *style-noun* is *adverb* transformed from *adjective* *meaning-noun* into *adjective*, *adjective-prefix**adjective* *meaning-noun*.",
        "*posessive-pronoun* *judgement-adjective* *album-subject* is *meaning-noun* by design –– *adjective* *style-noun* by way of *judgement-adjective*, *adjective* *technique-noun*.",
        "*posessive-pronoun* new *album-subject* is *adverb* a more *adjective*, *adjective* work than *posessive-pronoun* last, and suggests its *technique-noun-plural* are as much *adjective* as they are *adjective*.",
        "If the opening track *adverb* assumes the *adjective* *technique-noun* of *adjective* *style-noun*, it prefers to *technique-verb* rather than to *technique-verb*.",
        "For all the *adjective* *technique-noun* heard on *posessive-pronoun* last *album-subject*, these performances are for the most part *adjective-prefix**adjective* and *judgement-adjective*, making *posessive-pronoun* songs *comparative* than their *adjective* *technique-noun-plural* initially suggest."
    ],
    "sentence-conclusion": [
        "And, forgiving the obligatory *adjective* *technique-noun*, one can almost detect the *adjective* *style-noun* that might have subsumed this otherwise-*adjective* *style-noun* *meaning-noun*.",
        "Still, seeing these *adjective* songs through their *adjective* *technique-noun-plural* is more than *adjective*, if only for the promised *adjective-prefix**adjective* *technique-noun-plural* and *adjective* *judgement-noun*."
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post relevant parts (i.e. a minimal runnable example) of your code into your question so that it remains relevant for other users when your code changes on Github. This also helps us understand what you really want to achieve and what your actual issue is.

Comment: Could you store replacements in a list and prior to replacing, check the list to see if it exists already in the list?

Comment: This sounds like another instance of a "card shuffling" problem, of which there are several good questions and answers already on the site. If there are specific constraints (like the collection of words being particularly large) please elaborate. Otherwise this is probable best solved by shuffling the collection (or a list of indecies or keys if appropriate) and then picking the first n items from that list.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a new method in Array (we use ! to denote that the original array is modified):

```
class Array
  def deal!
    self.slice!(rand(self.length-1))
  end
end

foo = [1,2,3,4,5]

puts "deal #{foo.deal!}"
puts "deal #{foo.deal!}"
puts "deal #{foo.deal!}"
puts "deal #{foo.deal!}"
puts "deal #{foo.deal!}"
```